# ##[error]Unhandled: Unable to locate executable file: 'docker'

Tags: azure-devops

while i'm running azure pipeline in building images i'm getting this error
##[error]Unhandled: Unable to locate executable file: 'docker'. Please verify either the file path exists or the file can be found within a directory specified by the PATH environment variable. Also verify the file has a valid extension for an executable file.

Comment: Are you using self-hosted agent? On Microsoft hosted agent, the docker is preinstalled and can get from `path` env.

Comment: it's even on MS hosted agents that I'm starting to see recently on ubuntu-22.04. Using `DockerInstaller` didn't seem to help either. This was working fine until recently, and removing `container` if you have it along with `pool.image` seems to have fixed it.